# How to extract string between dash with regex in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string in javascript:

```
 const str = "bugfix/SOME-9234-add-company"; // output should be SOME-9234
 const str2 = "SOME/SOME-933234-add-company"; // output should be SOME-933234
 const str3 = "test/SOME-5559234-add-company"; // output should be SOME-5559234
```

and I want to extract the `SOME-..` until the first `-` char.

I use this regex but didn't work. what is the correct regex?

```
const s = "bugfix/SOME-9234-add-company";
const r1 = s.match(/SOME-([1-9])/);
const r2 = s.match(/SOME-(.*)/);
const r3 = s.match(/SOME-(.*)-$/);

console.log({ r1, r2, r3 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `/(SOME-[\d]+)/g` regex, *e.g.*

```js
const strings = [
  "bugfix/SOME-9234-add-company", // output should be SOME-9234
  "SOME/SOME-933234-add-company", // output should be SOME-933234
  "test/SOME-5559234-add-company" // output should be SOME-5559234
];
strings.forEach(string => {
  const regex = /(SOME-[\d]+)/g;
  const found = string.match(regex);
  console.log(found[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

In some steps to explain regex:

```js
const s = "bugfix/SOME-9234-add-company";

// This one is close, but will return only ONE digit 
console.log( s.match(/SOME-([1-9])/) );
// What you wanted:
console.log( s.match(/SOME-([1-9]+)/) ); // note the +, meaning '1 or more'

// Explanation about your other two tries: 
// 1. This'll give you everything after 'SOME':
console.log( s.match(/SOME-(.*)/) );
// 2. This'll match if the line 'ends with -' (= -$)
console.log( s.match(/SOME-(.*)-$/) );
 
// What you wanted:
console.log( s.match(/SOME-(.*?)-/) ); // Not end of line, but 'ungreedy'(the ?) which does 'untill the first - you encounter'

// instead of Using [1-9], you can also use \d, digits, for readability:
console.log( s.match(/SOME-(\d+)/) );
```

Answer (score 0):

`/(SOME-[^-]+)/` should work well. (capture everything what is not an hyphen after `SOME-`)

Or, if you know you have only digits, close to what you tried:

`/(SOME-[1-9]+)/`

You were missing a `+` to take more than one character.

I also changed the parenthesis to capture exactly what you show in the question (i.e., including the part with `SOME`)

Answer (score 0):

If You don't want to use regex then this could be simple

```
const s = "bugfix/SOME-9234-add-company";
const str2 = "SOME/SOME-933234-add-company";
const str3 = "test/SOME-5559234-add-company";
const r1 = s.split("/")[1].split("-",2).join("-"); // "SOME-9234"
const r2 = str2.split("/")[1].split("-",2).join("-"); // "SOME-933234"
const r3 = str3.split("/")[1].split("-",2).join("-"); // "SOME-5559234"
```

Comment: While these work, using array manipulation on string is often something you want to stay away from :)

Comment: @Martijn why so ? can you please explain it :) ?

Comment: Array operations are (most of the time) slower than string manipulation. Not really sure where regex scores in that scale, but simple string manipulation is very fast. Arrays have a larger amount of overhead. It wont matter notably in this case, but on a project scale it adds up

Answer (score 0):

In the patterns that you tried:

- `$` asserts the end of the string,
- `[1-9]` matches a single digit 1-9 without the 0
- `.*` will match any characters without a newline 0+ times

There is no need for capturing groups, you could match:

```
\bSOME-\d+
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KYSTlv/1)

Note that [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) will return an array, from which you could take the 0 index.

```js
[
  "bugfix/SOME-9234-add-company",
  "SOME/SOME-933234-add-company",
  "test/SOME-5559234-add-company"

].forEach(s => console.log(s.match(/\bSOME-\d+/)[0]));
```